# External CSS not loading in window.print()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to print a specific content area of my page. My problem is I have created separate `CSS` file for the content of this print area. But that external `CSS` is not working (loading) in browser print popup. I am sure file path is correct.

This is how I tried it:

```
function printReceipt(el) {
  var docHead = "<html>\
                  <head>\
                    <title></title>\
                    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/receipt-print.css' type='text/css' media='print' />\
                  </head>\
                  <body>";
  var docFoot = " </body>\
                 </html>";
  var docBody     = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
  var defaultBody = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = docHead+docBody+docFoot;
  //document.close(); 
  //window.focus(); 
  //setTimeout(function() {
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = defaultBody;
  //}, 1000);    
  //return true;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Also check in this way. Problem is sill same.

```
function printReceipt(el) {
  var w = window.open();
  w.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
  w.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/receipt-print.css">');
  w.document.write('</head><body >');
  w.document.write(document.getElementById(el).innerHTML);
  w.document.write('</body></html>');

  w.document.close();
  w.focus();
  w.print();
  w.close();
  return true;
}
```

Any ideas and suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try with `document.write`? `innerHTML` ignores the styles.

Comment: can you create a different file to use as an iframe already linked with the CSS file and load when you need it, then change the innerHTML and print that iframe window

Comment: May I know the reason this is not working? I have seen some questions and answers here and some answers are given like I have tried and they are accepted. But I don't know why this not works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was you were printing the page without waiting for the styles and resources to load.

You should wait for the page to load before trying to print it or you can try using inline styles.

```
function printReceipt(el) {
  var w = window.open();

  w.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
  w.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/receipt-print.css">');
  w.document.write('</head><body >');
  w.document.write(document.getElementById(el).innerHTML);
  w.document.write('<script type="text/javascript">addEventListener("load", () => { print(); close(); })</script></body></html>');

  w.document.close();
  w.focus();
}
```

Comment: Let me check it out

Comment: not working for me

Comment: bootstrap table CSS is not applying to print page