# CSS not working when creating and opening print page

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create some elements to print and use the CSS of a stylesheet I already have, but the style is not applied:

```
let printWindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=600,width=800');
printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print</title>');
printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://my.website/css/mystylesheet.css" type="text/css" />');
printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
printWindow.document.write('<p id="test">Hello</p>');
printWindow.document.close();
printWindow.focus();
printWindow.print();
printWindow.close();
```

And in the css file:

```
#test {
  color: green;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

Update: The following did not work either:

```
let printData = '';
printData += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://my.website/css/mystylesheet.css" type="text/css" />';
printData += '<p id="test">Hello</p>'

let printWindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=600,width=800');
printWindow.document.write(data);
printWindow.document.close();
printWindow.focus();
printWindow.print();
printWindow.close();
```

Comment: document.write DOES NOT work like building a string line by line. When you write the opening tag, it closes it.

Comment: Oh! So every time it overrides the previous line?

Comment: no, when you write out '<body>' or '<head>' the browser will close that tag. Just use a string and write once. It is more efficient.

Comment: Thank you, I still couldn't make it work. I updated the post at the bottom with my new attempt

Comment: @epascarello update: There is a weird behavior now, the CSS does not work, but when I click "Cancel" on the print window, then the CSS suddenly updates on the second window

Comment: maybe add a timeout to delay the printing so it has time to fully load.

Comment: But why does this happen? I have the `.print()` method only at the end, after `.document.write(data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the css time to load. It won't need much but this snippet gives it generous time just to prove a point.

```
<script>
let printData = '';
printData += '<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="mystylesheet.css" type="text/css" /></head>';
printData += '<body><p id="test">Hello</p></body>'

let printWindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=600,width=800');
printWindow.document.write(printData);
printWindow.document.close();
printWindow.focus();
function myprint() {
  printWindow.print();
  printWindow.close();
  }
setTimeout( myprint,  1000)
</script>
```

Comment: Nice, it works. Is there a way to wait as little as possible and launch the print window as soon as everything loads? Or I will have to put some arbitrary amount of time? In the following post, they used load() inside the write(). But as the comment above suggested I should not have multiple writes()?.. Or that's ok: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68435166/external-css-not-loading-in-window-print

Comment: Maybe play around with getting the new page to wait until it is fully loaded itself and get it to do the printing? And then perhaps it needs to close itself, otherwise you'll be back to having the original page having to wait an arbitary time.

Answer (score 0):

I write the same code but delete printWindow.close() to see the output

```js
        function test(){
            let printWindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=600,width=800');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print</title>');
            printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/mystylesheet.css" type="text/css" />');
            printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
            printWindow.document.write('<p id="test">Hello</p>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.focus();
            printWindow.print();
        }
```

```css
#test {
  color: green;
}

h1{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 href="#" onclick="test()">test</h1>
```

this the result when I clicked on 'test' word:
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Qq6.png)

**So make sure that you put the right path to the css file**

Comment: I just checked and that path is correct. I also noticed that the CSS doesn't work still, but when I click "Cancel" on the print window, then it updates the CSS (You can see it in the second window that it changes colors as soon as I close the print window). Why?