# How to open the print() window right after the CSS files finished loading?

Tags: javascript

After an issue with the CSS not working when using the `print()` method, I was given the answer here that it's because it takes time for the CSS files to load, and it was correct.

So now I have an arbitrary timeout set to let the CSS files load:

```
<script>
let printData = '';
printData += '<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="mystylesheet.css" type="text/css" /></head>';
printData += '<body><p id="test">Hello</p></body>'

let printWindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=600,width=800');
printWindow.document.write(printData);
printWindow.document.close();
printWindow.focus();

function myprint() {
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();
}

setTimeout(myprint,  1000)
</script>
```

But instead of waiting too much (or too little) by giving some arbitrary time, is there a way to update the code such that it will launch the print screen as soon as everything finishes loading?

Comment: Did you try the [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#stylesheet_load_events) event?

Comment: Have you tried to attach a onload eventlistener to the printWindow body ?

Comment: No however I did see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68435166/external-css-not-loading-in-window-print, but it's a bit different because I have a single `write()`, so wasn't sure how to place it here. Should I just add a separate `write()` for the CSS links with onload as seen in this post?

Answer (score 0):

call myPrint() in $( document ).ready() method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).